# How to compare characters of two text files using batch and replace it?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i have a two text files named, `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`

*file1.txt contains*

```
abc@d
```

*file2.txt contains*

```
abcad
```

How to compare both of them and leave the same letters as it is.. and only replace the part of symbols.. *for example :* replacing only 4th character which is @

*Note* : The position of the character will be varies..

*The code i used to get `file2.txt` output is,*

```
@echo off
cls
set /p input=type here:
set input0=!input:@=a!
echo %input0% >file2.txt
pause>nul
```

Comment: So you want to search for something in one file and update it in the other file? So you want to end up with 2 files that are exactly the same?

Comment: yes. automatically search symbols from one file and replace it in the another file at same position..

Comment: Then you need to show me an example of file1 and file2. For now it seems like you want to copy one file to another.

Comment: Then you don't even read file2, just copy file1 to file2

Comment: Agreed, replace file 1 with file 2, unless there is some reason that can't be done, such as file 1 is a list of strings to match and dile 2 is a file with many other entries

Comment: i know the file1.txt will be the same which i need as new output.. Actually am trying something like encryt and decrypt.. File1.txt is user input. Now its encryt as file2.txt Now i want the same to be revert back using decrypt. So, this is the reason why i need same file1.txt as output (but, in our case user doesn't have file1.txt, they have only file2.txt , so in behind we have file1.txt that's why i compare both to get rid of that symbol comparison)

Comment: But, now it is even more unclear what you want.. why not just use an encryption tool?

Comment: Pls visit this link » https://philiphacker.blogspot.com/p/testing.html?m=1

i have uploaded examples here... for better understanding...

Comment: ok, you need to understand that scripting uses certain special characters to create functions. Using `delayedexpansion` will create an issue for `!` other items such as parenthesis `()` and redirect, or poison characters `<>` should be escaped using a caret `^` so as you can currently see, you are really asking us to build the script for you, which is off topic here. Build some more, then come back and ask when you get stuck... and Good luck! `:)`